# Spring - avoid mixing versions

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-data

During run my Spring boot application I get following error:

An attempt was made to call the method `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient.builder()Lorg/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient$Builder; but it does not exist. Its class, org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient, is available from the following locations:`

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/Wicia/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web-reactive/5.0.0.M4/spring-web-reactive-5.0.0.M4.jar!/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/C:/Users/Wicia/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web-reactive/5.0.0.M4/spring-web-reactive-5.0.0.M4.jar
```

Action:

```
Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient
```

---

I have found a clue that I should specify common spring versions (not mixing it) for all artifacts, but how to do it?

This is my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.M4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web-reactive</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.M4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You are using Spring Boot... Then don't mess around with versions. Use one version for the `spring-boot-starter-parent` which should be either your parent or an import in the `dependencyManagement` section in your pom. All other versions will be managed by Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT define the dependency versions in your pom.xml if that dependency is managed by Spring. Instead use `spring-boot-starter-parent` as a parent.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

Spring-boot-parent has versions defined for almost all of the popular dependencies, so by default you can skip defining versions. Define it only if you get an POM error (meaning that you added a unique dependency which is not managed by Spring Boot)

Comment: Good solution, thanks :) Now I have added version for artifact "spring-web-reactive" beacause some classes from "org.springframework.web.reactive" were missing and still this error occurs :/

Comment: I don't know what is that package but the latest version of it in mvnrepository is <version>5.0.0.M4</version>.

Comment: General advice: Do NOT play with versions except you have a very good reason for it AND you really-really know what are you doing! :)

Comment: You should use `spring-webflux` rather than `spring-web-reactive`.

Comment: @Selindek Ok, I am only wondering about such scenario - I want to add class X to my project. I search it in maven repository, found it under artifact Y version Z and now what - how to determine which versions of dependencies I should use and which not? (there must by some Very-Wise-Guys who now how to do it :)

Comment: First add it without version tag. There is a very good chance Spring has a managed version for it. If you got a maven error then it's up to you. There will be no versioning problems with any Spring classes.